# Pandas upsample dataframe and fill with NaN

Tags: python, pandas

I simply want the following dataframe to be resampled to 10 minutes rather than 30, and not fill the values with anything. Leave them as NaN.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Col1": [10, 20, 15, 30, 45],
                  "Col2": [13, 23, 18, 33, 48],
                  "Col3": [17, 27, 22, 37, 52]},
                  index=pd.date_range("11:00", "13:00", freq="30min"))
df.resample("10T").bfill(limit=1)
```

Almost does what is wanted, but the method should just do nothing and return the resampled dataframe, so the dataframe wanted is the following:

```
                     Col1  Col2  Col3
2021-04-22 11:00:00  10.0  13.0  17.0
2021-04-22 11:10:00   NaN   NaN   NaN
2021-04-22 11:20:00   NaN   NaN   NaN
2021-04-22 11:30:00  20.0  23.0  27.0
2021-04-22 11:40:00   NaN   NaN   NaN
2021-04-22 11:50:00   NaN   NaN   NaN
2021-04-22 12:00:00  15.0  18.0  22.0
2021-04-22 12:10:00   NaN   NaN   NaN
2021-04-22 12:20:00   NaN   NaN   NaN
2021-04-22 12:30:00  30.0  33.0  37.0
2021-04-22 12:40:00   NaN   NaN   NaN
2021-04-22 12:50:00   NaN   NaN   NaN
2021-04-22 13:00:00  45.0  48.0  52.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially was going to ask this question, but found the answer as I was searching. The method wanted is the `asfreq` method, which :

> Return the values at the new freq, essentially a reindex.

Which shows that this upsampling is basically a reindex. Specifically:

```
df.resample("10T").asfreq()
```

Another possibility is to use a `reindex`, which can be done in the following way:

```
df.reindex(pd.date_range("11:00", "13:00", freq="10min"))
```

Both of these achieve the desired dataframe.